Repainting problem using request.security() in replay mode even though only using confirmed data
// This Pine Script™ code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © Lynext

//@version=5
indicator("Repainting Problem", overlay = true)
higherTF = input.timeframe("5", "Higher Timeframe", group = "General Configuration")

const int atrLen = 10
bulkyCandleATR = 2.1

var float lastHigh = 0
var float lastLow = 0
bool newBulkyCandle = false

h = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTF, high[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
l = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTF, low[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
tr = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTF, ta.tr[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
htfATR = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTF, ta.atr(atrLen)[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
cnf = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTF, barstate.isconfirmed[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

if barstate.isconfirmed and cnf
    if (h != lastHigh and l != lastLow) and (tr > htfATR * bulkyCandleATR)
        newBulkyCandle := true
        lastHigh := h
        lastLow := l

plotchar(newBulkyCandle ? high : na, "", "✅", size = size.tiny)
if newBulkyCandle
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(lastHigh, "#.##"), yloc = yloc.belowbar, textcolor = color.white, color = color.black, style = label.style_label_up)

When the script is executed realtime :
realtime
On replay mode :
replay
Can anyone explain to me why does this demo repaint on replay mode ? My chart is on 3-min timeframe and the higher timeframe is set to 5-min timeframe. Did I miss something to avoid repainting ?
Ticker is BTCUSDT.P / MEXC
Tried everything on this page : https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/concepts/other-timeframes-and-data/#higher-timeframe-data
I expect to have the same things plotted in realtime bars with replay mode because I only plot based on confirmed bars in the current timeframe and the higher timeframe, so data should be exactly the same.
